# jQuery function that only sees TEXT and ignores HTML?

Tags: php, jquery

**Issue**

I have a jquery POST code that sends data to PHP and PHP replies.

*PHP replies like this:*

```
echo '<div class="blabla">hello world!</div>';
```

And I want to do something like this:

```
if (data == 'hello world') { 
do something
}
```

This is my jQuery:

```
            $.post("events.php?action=send", { data :  $(this).serialize() }, function(data) 
            {
                $("#processing").html('');              
                if (data == 'hello world')                  
                {
                    $(".error").html(data);
                }
                else
                {
                    $("#comments").html(data);
                }
                submit.fadeIn("slow");  
            });
```

**problem**

If I will only use if data == 'something', without the HTML, it will fail.

Is there a function that ignores the HTML and only sees the TEXT inside the HTML tags?

Thanks!

Comment: You mean `.text()`? http://api.jquery.com/text/

Comment: @Ian that will only work if it is a DOM element.

Comment: @Hogan But you can wrap an HTML string with `$()` and manipulate it. `$("<div>asdf<span>fdsa</span></div>").text()` produces "asdffdsa".

Comment: @Ian - "Wrapping" it like that converts it to a DOM element.  Works fine, but there are costs.  That was my point.

Comment: @Hogan Costs? Yes, to use jQuery methods, there are costs. It's not like it appends it to the **actual** DOM or anything.

Comment: @Ian.  Um... NO.  "As mentioned, jQuery uses the browser"s .innerHTML property to parse the passed HTML and insert it into the current document."  See this page. http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery2

Comment: @Hogan "In most cases, jQuery creates a new <div> element and sets the innerHTML property of the element to the HTML snippet that was passed in."

Comment: @Hogan If you look at the jQuery source, all it does it create a document fragment and works with that. It never appends to the real DOM. That doesn't make any sense...

Comment: @Ian - If it is a single tag it does not create a fragment -- see call on line 151 (`context && context.nodeType ? context.ownerDocument || context : document,`) where it passes in ownerDocument and line 526 - `if ( parsed ) { return [context.createElement(parsed[1)];}`

Comment: @Hogan Yes I saw that, but I thought it was obvious from your link - "If the HTML is more complex than a single tag without attributes, as it is in the above example, the actual creation of the elements is handled by the browser's innerHTML mechanism." so I didn't need to mention. Either way, the point is that nothing is appended to the real DOM, just dynamically created elements, which is expected.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you pass the string into the jQuery constructor, which will return a DOM object, on which you can then use your standard jQuery methods on it.

For example:

```
var data = '<div class="blabla">hello world!</div>';

if($(data).text() == 'hello world!'){
    console.log('hello world is the content');
}
```

`data` will remain a string and will act as a string, but you are comparing the `.text()` of the DOM element.

*Note*: On a large HTML string, this could take time to be processed into a DOM element. Use wisely. Ideally you should be using JSON with your AJAX requests etc.

Comment: The .html() reference returns a string, but I have added in a bit of clarification.

Comment: I think you're looking for `.text()`, not `.html()`

Comment: With the basic div example above, there's no huge difference between the two AFAIK. However, to accommodated nested elements, `.tex()` would be best. Corrected.

Comment: @MichaelWright Absolutely right. I was just assuming it wasn't always as simple as a single tag, so why not be safe and use what actually gets the inner text? :)

Answer (score -2):

Is this what you're looking for?

.text()

http://api.jquery.com/text/

You can put the string in jQuery (" $() ") so you will get $(data).text() and that will return the string as text;

Comment: This is a link only answer.  Ya really need more for an answer on SO.